# R: Social network - max values based on conditions in different columns and rows

Tags: r, social-networking

I would like to transform the following sample data based on a fictional trade survey example. Think of it that Country A says it exports to country B (Row 2, Export=1), while Country B says it does not import from A (Row 4, Import=0), and vice versa. I now want to get the max values (=1) for all these matches in the dataset, i.e. in this case Import in Row 4 would be =1).

```
> df <- data.frame("Sender" = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
+ "Receiver" = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), 
+ "Export"= c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
+ "Import" = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0))
> df
  Sender Receiver Export Import
1      A        A      0      0
2      A        B      1      1
3      A        C      0      1
4      B        A      0      0
5      B        B      0      0
6      B        C      0      1
7      C        A      0      0
8      C        B      0      0
9      C        C      0      0
```

The solution should be

```
  Sender Receiver Export Import Export_MAX Import_MAX
1      A        A      0      0          0          0
2      A        B      1      1          1          1
3      A        C      0      1          0          1
4      B        A      0      0          1          1
5      B        B      0      0          0          0
6      B        C      0      1          0          1
7      C        A      0      0          1          0
8      C        B      0      0          1          0
9      C        C      0      0          0          0
```

I searched many ways to do that in this forum and elsewhere, but couldn't find a solution so far. I was thinking of something along the lines of applying a max function on the "Import" & "Export" columns, conditional on the values given in "Sender" & "Receiver", but I didn't get as far as to be able to report code here.

Any ideas out there? Your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own solution, in case someone gets to the same issue.

```
df$Pairs <- paste(df$Sender,df$Receiver,sep = "-")
values <- df$Pairs[df$Export==1]
values2 <- df$Pairs[df$Import==1]

df$Import[df$Pairs %in% gsub("(\\w+)-(\\w+)","\\2-\\1", values)] <- 1
df$Export[df$Pairs %in% gsub("(\\w+)-(\\w+)","\\2-\\1", values2)] <- 1
```

The first line brings all sender-receiver combination into a character field - seperated by "-". The second and third line create pair combination for each row where the export/import conditions are 1. The final two rows use gsub to match all instances where the word combination sender-receiver or receiver sender is a match, and replace these values with 1.

Solution (directly in the Export/Import columns):

```
  Sender Receiver Export Import Export_MAX Import_MAX
1      A        A      0      0          0          0
2      A        B      1      1          1          1
3      A        C      0      1          0          1
4      B        A      1      1          1          1
5      B        B      0      0          0          0
6      B        C      0      1          0          1
7      C        A      1      0          1          0
8      C        B      1      0          1          0
9      C        C      0      0          0          0
```